# How to disable spin buttons in razor view of asp.net?

Tags: asp.net

In model class column name is `public int? CTScore { get; set; }` and in Razor view I want to use this as `@Html.EditorFor(model => model.CTScore)`.

It is showing as editor box along with Up/Down arrow spin buttons, but I need not show those spin buttons. How to do?

Any help is appreciated.

Comment: What are spin buttons? Can you get more specific and show us your code, screenshots and where excactly your problem is?

Answer (score 4):

It sounds like Razor is adding `type="number"` to your `input` field, which causes modern browsers to show the spin buttons. If you want to disable this, and use `type="text"` instead, you can add a [`DataType`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.componentmodel.dataannotations.datatype.aspx) attribute to your property:

```
[DataType(DataType.Text)]
public int? CTScore { get; set; }
```

Answer (score 3):

The following line is what you need.

```
@Html.EditorFor(model => model.CTScore, new { htmlAttributes = new { @type="text" } })
```

Answer (score 0):

Based on this link:

[Remove slider/spinner from input type of number with MVC 5 EditorFor](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34711928/remove-slider-spinner-from-input-type-of-number-with-mvc-5-editorfor)

you can add this to your CSS file:

```
input[type=number]::-webkit-inner-spin-button, 
input[type=number]::-webkit-outer-spin-button { 
  -webkit-appearance: none; 
  margin: 0; 
}
```

This will remove the spinners, and allows only numbers to be entered, not text.