# How can I have a spin (up/down) button in razor view of asp.net

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-4, razor

I'm trying to add a spin (up/down) button in razor view on a mvc asp.net project.

I saw a predecent post that it not have this probleme (he want inverse of my problem)  ...
[How to disable spin buttons in razor view of asp.net?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21967074/how-to-disable-spin-buttons-in-razor-view-of-asp-net?answertab=oldest#tab-top)

In my model I have this :

```
public int? fPeriodeValid { get; set; }
```

And in my view this :

```
@Html.TextBoxFor(model => model.fPeriodeValid)

@Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.fPeriodeValid)
```

I want to see up/down button but it's not work ...

So did you have an any idea why it's ok for him but not for me ?

(sorry for my english I'm french ^^ )
Thanks for your answer :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are explicitly telling Razor to build a `TextBox`. If you let the view engine decide which is the best component for your property, you will get a spinner for numeric fields. Instead of

```
@Html.TextBoxFor(model => model.fPeriodeValid)
```

write

```
@Html.EditorFor(model => model.fPeriodeValid)
```

Comment: I tried `EditorFor` just now, and it works fine. Hover the mouse over the input, or place the cursor in the input, the spinner should shown then.

Comment: It would of course depend on browser support. Not all browser support Number input type: http://caniuse.com/#feat=input-number

Comment: I tried EditorFor just now too ( and before, because it's generated by default ^^ ). So it's my browsers that not support this :( Thanx for your help

Comment: Which browser do you use? Have you tried another browser, just to see if it really works or not?

Comment: I use ie 8.0 and firefox 26.0, I can't update any of them, so I don't tried another browser ... I'm waiting (3h) to go at home to test this on my personal laptop. But according to the link of Michael Fürstenberg my browsers are not supported.