# Remove slider/spinner from input type of number with MVC 5 EditorFor

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, razor

I am using Razor with MVC 5 for a model which has an integer value. If I use

```
@Html.EditorFor(model => model.WeekPrice, new { htmlAttributes = new { @class = "form-control" } })
```

I get a slider/spinner appearing in the text box; the generated HTML is:

```
<input type="number" ...
```

If I use `@Html.TextboxFor(model` or change the data type to `decimal` the spinner disappears and the HTML input type changes to text.

How can I use `EditorFor` and supress the spinner?

Comment: Whats wrong with using `TextBoxFor()`? The `EditorFor()` method is specifically designed to generate the `type` attribute based on the type of property (or based on the `[DataType]` attribute) so that it uses the browsers HTML5 inputs

Comment: Simple, I prefer the styling. And I also want to understand how to achieve this.

Comment: What styling? (you can achieve exactly the same using `TextboxFor()`). And if you really want to use the `EditorFor()` method, you could try `new { htmlAttributes = new { @class = "form-control", type = "text" }` but thats just extra code

Comment: There is a difference in the shape of the text box. However, if you put your comment in an answer I'd be happy to accept it.

Comment: @StephenMuecke that doesn't work for me in Chrome. https://dotnetfiddle.net/rBIZON

Comment: I'm really not sure why you don't just use `@Html.TextBoxFor(m => m.WeekPrice, new { @class = "form-control" }` which will generate a standard `type="text"` input. Note that `type="number"` will use the browsers implementation of a number input which will vary in appearance across different browsers

Comment: I can use `TextBoxFor` and probably will; more a sense of frustration at not initially realising what was adding the spinner (I was moving from an earlier version of various components. Thanks.

Comment: Doesn't the TextboxFor also make it so that the keyboard is opened on a mobile device since it is now just a regular old input field? I really would like to get rid of the annoying extra icons in browsers while still being able to pop-up the numberpad on a mobile device.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

I don't see any reason why can't you use `TextBoxFor()` for this purpose cause essentially you are trying to display it as normal `TextBox` control rather a numeric up/down control. Anyways, you can use CSS to achieve this. Taken from [CSS Tricks: Turn Off Number Input Spinners](https://css-tricks.com/snippets/css/turn-off-number-input-spinners/)

```
input[type=number]::-webkit-inner-spin-button, 
input[type=number]::-webkit-outer-spin-button { 
  -webkit-appearance: none; 
  margin: 0; 
}
```